# Migrate from CVS to Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2012

Tags: tfs

Is there any tool or method available for migrating code, history, tags from CVS to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool from [Timely Migration for moving CVS history](http://www.timelymigration.com/) to Team Foundation Server. I have used these tools (although not with CVS) and they work pretty well.

Unlike CS-Convertor it does not have a per file licencing which is awesome and you can use it as many times as you like.

Comment: You have to buy it Raj :) But you can use the trial to prove it works

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [CS-Converter](http://www.componentsoftware.com/Products/converter/index.htm), it's conversion tool, used to migrate from various legacy version control systems (such as RCS, CVS, Subversion and Visual SourceSafe) to Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) system.

Fore more info:

[Migrating CVS and Subversion repositories to Team Foundation Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/01/11/migrating-cvs-and-subversion-repositories-to-team-foundation-server.aspx)

Comment: CS-Converter is discontinued tool